# Side by side comparison of data in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am using SSIS package for my migration where I am migrating the Source data to destination database.
Now, I need to confirm that data are correctly migrated to destination database table.

Currently, I am using 2 scripts, one from source and other from destination. Picking up some data manually and comparing it in excel sheet.

I am wondering if there is any way to compare it in SQL itself.

Comment: That's pretty vague. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `except` operator.

```
--rows in A that aren’t in or are diff than B
SELECT ‘A’, * FROM A 
EXCEPT 
SELECT ‘A’, * FROM B

UNION ALL

--rows in B that aren’t in or are diff than A
SELECT ‘B’, * FROM B
EXCEPT
SELECT ‘B’, * FROM A
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

If you need to know exactly what values of each row are different then the SQL option gets a little gross and you’re better off just using the built in spreadsheet compare tool in Office.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-spreadsheet-compare-13fafa61-62aa-451b-8674-242ce5f2c986

Comment: I've upvoted this answer because (as far as I can see) it does what's needed. However, an alternative format for the above is to use the two SELECTS above as derived tables (e.g., D1 and D2). Then instead of the UNION, use  `FULL OUTER JOIN` (on, say, D1.id = D2.id), and potentially `ORDER BY ISNULL(D1.Id, D2.id)`. This will give you a side-by-side comparison rather than a single list with all mismatches. Same information, just formatted a bit differently.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely an option.  Possibly a good option for slim tables that you can visually scan, but probably not for wide ones.  You would also need to write some logic to compare columns and eliminate rows that are identical, unless you’re okay with those appearing in your output.

Comment: Your code has the fundamental logic to gets rid of identical rows. I was suggesting using your code and tweaking it a little, for example, using `(SELECT * FROM A EXCEPT SELECT * FROM B) AS D1` then doing FULL OUTER JOIN to the equivalent in D2. The main difference in the answer would be cosmetic: instead of one list, the alternative I mentioned just shows rows with any difference side-by-side (or side-by-NULLs if one side doesn't exist). Whether the OP wants to use a list or a side-by-side is up to them.